# scheme apply to a list including elements with quote

Tags: scheme, apply, quote

I am working on a scheme project and I encountered with a problem with quotes.
When I use (apply + '(1 2 '3)) racket gives an error,  on the other hand (+ 1 2 '3) works fine. At some point in the project I need to be able to do something like (apply + '(1 2 '3)) since I am taking the values from a given file and I have no freedom to use (+ 1 2 '3). I tried to write an add function that adds all the values in the list but it didn't work either. How can I solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Kindly Format your Question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'x` is an abbreviation for `(quote x)`. In early lisps it was a reader macro and today some print routines will actually print `(quote x)` as `'x` for convenience. Even when the printer chooses to print it as an abbriavtion it still a list with two elements so `(car ''x)` is `quote`.

`(+ '1 '2 '3)` works fine because all arguments are being evaluated. `+` gets evaluated to a procedural object `#<+>` (just a procedural representation of an implementation of global variable `+`), `'1` evaluates to it's data, the number `1` and so on. In the end application of the procedure happens on the arguments `(1 2 3)`. Numbers are self evaluating so if you were not to quote them `1` would evaluate to 1 and so on and you get the same result. Not all values are self evaluating.

With `(apply + '(1 2 3))` all 3 arguments get evaluate. `apply` and `+` both to procedural objects and `'(1 2 3)` to the list `(1 2 3)`. The procedure `#<+>` gets applied with the arguments `(1 2 3)`

With `(apply + '(1 2 '3))` all 3 arguments gets evaluated. `apply` and `+` both to procedural objects and `'(1 2 '3)` to the list `(1 2 (quote 3))`. The evaluator only looks at the outer quote so the `3` is still quoted and now it's part of the data. The procedure `#<+>` gets applied with the arguments `(1 2 (quote 3))`. It won't work since `#<+>` only knows how to add numbers and not lists. You can expect a contract violation, an error of some kind.

When evaluated the result is data. If you have more quotes besides the outer one it isn't a language command any more but a list with the symbol `quote` and a second value. It's not handled specially like qith outer quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the meaning of the quote `'`. 
The expression ' means "produce a value that prints as ".

For example `'3` produces the value 3 since the value 3 is printed as 3.

In `'(1 b)` you get a list whose first element is the number 1 and whose second element is the symbol b.

Now you need to know one more thing about the quote. The quote is a reader abbreviation. When `'<something>` is read, the reader produces the form `(quote <something>). This means that`'(1 'b)`produces the list`(1 (quote b))`. This is a list whose second element is the list`(quote b)`, where`quote` is the symbol quote.

In your example you tried to `(apply + '(1 2 '3))`. The value produced by `'(1 2 '3)` is the list (1 2 (quote 3)). Since `+` adds only numbers, you got an error message.

If you want to read in numbers from a file, then read them as numbers and everything ought to be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the problem with (apply +  '(1 2 '3)). However, I don't understand why (+ 1 2 '3) works because basically '3 is not a number it is a list (quote 3) like you said.

Comment: When  `(+ 1 2 '3)` is evalauted, + is evaluted first (the result is plus function). Then the number 2 is evaluated - the result is the number 2. Then the expression `'3` is evaluated. The result is 3. Finally + is applied to 2 and 3.